# Compact connected metric space is $\varepsilon$-chainable.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> A compact metric space is connected if, and only if, its points are $\varepsilon$-chainable.

**Definition of $\varepsilon$-chain**: Two points $a, b \in X$ are said to be $\varepsilon$-chainable if, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists finitely many points $x_0, \ldots, x_m$, with $x_0 = a$ and $x_m = b$, such that $d(x_i, x_{i+1}) < \varepsilon$ for $i = 1, \ldots, m-1$.

The standard way to prove that a connected space is $\varepsilon$-chainable would be to fix $a \in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, and show that
$$A := \{x \in X;\text{ there exists an }\varepsilon\text{-chain between }x\text{ and a}\}$$
is non-empty, open and closed. This works in general, without the compactness hypothesis. However, with this assumption, I was wondering whether the following argument would suffice, since it is a much shorter proof:

Consider the open cover $\{B(x,\varepsilon/2)\}_{x \in X}$ of $X$. Given that $X$ is compact, there exists a finite cover, say $\{B(x_{j}, \varepsilon/2)\}_{1 \leq j \leq m}$. Now, we can construct a graph $\Gamma$ associated to this finite cover in the following way: two vertices $x_i$ and $x_j$ are connected if, and only if, $B(x_i, \varepsilon/2) \cap B(x_j, \varepsilon/2) \neq \varnothing$. If $\Gamma$ is a disconnected graph, we can write $X$ as a union of two disjoint open sets, which contradicts connectedness.

Comment: Your idea looks fine to me. It makes sense that compactness should make our life much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument you have given suffices just fine for proving that a connected metric space is $\varepsilon$-chainable, but it does not need to use compactness, nor does it benefit from compactness.

There is no need to pass to a finite subcover - you can look at the graph whose vertices consist of all balls $B(x,\varepsilon)$ and with an edge joining any two balls that intersect.  The (infinite) graph must be connected, otherwise as you argue, you obtain a separation of the space.

Note also there is really no need to cut the radii in half here - applying the argument with balls of radius $\varepsilon$ already proves that the space is $\varepsilon$-chainable, since if two balls intersect you can join their centers via the intersection point as an intermediary.

##### Remark.

While the graph approach may help with intuition, its worth noting that the proof could be stated just as concisely in terms of equivalence relations.  Namely, let $x\sim y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ can be joined by an $\varepsilon$ chain.  It is elementary to show this is an equivalence relation.  If $[x_0]\neq [y_0]$ are distinct equivalence classes in $X/\sim$, then for each $x\in [x_0]$ and $y\in [y_0]$ we have $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap B(y,\varepsilon)=\emptyset$, whereby $U=\bigcup_{x\in [x_0]}B(x,\varepsilon)$ and $V=\bigcup_{y\in X\backslash [x_0]}B(y,\varepsilon)$ are a separation of $X$.

The graph approach is using this exact same idea, with the help of the observation that two points are $\varepsilon$-chainable if and only if their corresponding vertices are in the same component of the graph, though as discussed in the comments, a bit of care is needed to be precise about what that means.

Comment: It would indeed be sufficient to use balls of radius $\varepsilon$. As you mentioned, we can connect any point with the center of its ball. However, compactness would be extremely important here, because the definition of $\varepsilon$-chainable requires a finite chain of points. If the graph were infinite and connected, we can guarantee a chain but not necessarily a finite one.

Comment: @test1 no, the connected component of a vertex in a graph is precisely the set of vertices (and their connecting edges) that can be joined by a finite path.

Comment: @test1 To elaborate on last comment - we have to be a little careful what we mean by a graph being connected - we could put a topology on it, but we don't really need to - instead, we can by definition, consider a graph connected if every pair of vertices can be joined by a (finite) edge path, since an infinite edge path from one vertex to another doesn't even make sense.  If a graph is not connected in this sense, then its vertex set is decomposed into at least two subsets with no member of one being joined by an edge to the other.  That decomposition immediately gives you your separation.

Comment: Interesting. So, the idea is that we are not even considering infinite chains, since they are not possible. There are only two options: either there is a finite connection or no connection. Is that it?

Comment: @test1 yes, exactly.

Comment: I just read it. It makes perfect sense to me now.